# Zoom HTML5 Canvas with gesture pinch on mobile with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I was wondering if someone might be able to help me solve a zoom issue that I'm having with my mobile app.

Basically, I'm using a HTML5 canvas (because I want to be able to draw on it later) and would like to be able to zoom in on particular areas of the canvas using pinch gestures. Also the ability to pan around the canvas image.

Currently, I am using Hammer.js.

**The code below sort of works, but the image jumps around and is really sensitive to zoom gestures. As in the zoom is not proportional to the gesture.**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('geomap');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
    var mc = new Hammer.Manager(canvas);
    var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();
    mc.add([pinch]);    // add to the Manager

    imageObj.src = './images/MapCanvas.png';

    var canvasHammer = {
        scale : 1,      // Scale of the image
        xLast : 0,      // Last location X on screen
        yLast : 0,      // Last location Y on screen
        xImage : 0,     // Last location X on image
        yImage : 0      // Last location Y on image
    };

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        context.scale(canvasHammer.scale, canvasHammer.scale);
    };

    // ============ GESTURE PINCH =================             
    mc.on("pinch", function(ev) {
        var zoomScale = ev.scale;

        var posX = ev.center.x;
        var posY = ev.center.y;

        // Find current location on screen
        var xScreen = posX;
        var yScreen = posY;

        canvasHammer.xImage = canvasHammer.xImage + ((xScreen - canvasHammer.xLast) / canvasHammer.scale);
        canvasHammer.yImage = canvasHammer.yImage + ((yScreen - canvasHammer.yLast) / canvasHammer.scale);

        canvasHammer.scale = zoomScale;

        // Determine the new location of the image
        var xNew = (xScreen - canvasHammer.xImage) / canvasHammer.scale;
        var yNew = (yScreen - canvasHammer.yImage) / canvasHammer.scale;

        canvasHammer.xLast = xScreen;
        canvasHammer.yLast = yScreen;

        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   // Clear the contents of the canvas.
        //context.save();
        context.drawImage(imageObj,xNew,yNew);      
        context.scale(zoomScale,zoomScale);
        //context.restore();
        $('.stuff').html("<p> Pinch : " + zoomScale + "<br>xNew : " + xNew + "<br>yNew : " + yNew + "</p>"); // For diagnostics!

    });


    $('#syncbutton').click(function() {
        if(hasInternetConnection())
        {
            alert('Nothing to sync. All maps currently up-to-date.');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('You need an internet connection to sync.');  
        }

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="map_editor" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Map Editor</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="pwdcontent">    
                <div class="mapcontainer">
                    <canvas id="geomap" class="mapCanvas"></canvas>
                    <div class="stuff"></div>   

                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks!